# Mock outer variable of tested function?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

```
const a = 1;

export const sum = b => a + b;
```

```
import { sum } from './sum';

it ('should return sum', () => {
  expect(sum(2)).toBe(3);
})
```

Is it possible to mock `a` with different values in this case?

Comment: Nope. If you consider that a collaborator, rather than an implementation detail, move it to a separate module.

Comment: This, or refactor so as to inject `a` as a dependency to a factory of sum: `const createSum = a => b => a+b`, then test `sum = createSum(4)`